# When I enter startapp command in django, app did not be added in project

Tags: python, django

I'm making website using django by pycharm pro version.

A command "python manage.py startapp 'app name'" worked well before,
but unexpectedly, the command does not work now.

when I enter the command in terminal,
in terminal, there is nothing difference.

but app doesn't develop in the file,

so I retry the command,

```
    CommandError: 'app name' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

commanderror raised...

what is the problem? I want to know the solution.

Comment: I'm assuming you deleted your app before retrying to create it.

Answer (score 0):

What name did you use with the "startapp"?

Comment: I tried 'python manage.py startapp likeapp'

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already created an app with that name, check your project folder